# any idea why the below parse cloud code parallel promises do not run?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Am trying to match urls depending on the id given that i dont know if the id given is an object id / title / shorturl code.

```js
var promises = [];
var id = request.params.id;
//short url
queryShortUrl = new Parse.Query("books");
queryShortUrl.limit = 1;
queryShortUrl.equalTo('shortURLcode',id);
promises.push(queryShortUrl.find());

//title
queryTitle = new Parse.Query("books");
queryTitle.limit = 1;
queryTitle.equalTo('bookTitle',id);
promises.push(queryNickname.find());


//objectId
queryObjectId = new Parse.Query("books");
promises.push(queryObjectId.get(request.params.genuid));

// run these
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
  console.log('res');
  response.success(arguments);
})
```

Comment: Could you add a rejectedCallback to see if there are any errors.

Comment: my bad, had a mismatch, defined queryTitle and then called queryNickname. Thanks for the help